# Windows Phone 8 IE10 Javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

IE10 has some wonderful enhancements in the HTML5 compliance area but remains a bear to develop JavaScript HTML5 when running on the WP8 as there is no way to debug the app except console messages.

Is there a remote debugging experience available for IE10 running on WP8 like the WebKit phone browsers have(see my video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNAjzFpNEj4 for example). When this is in place with a USB cable to desktop Safari debugging Javascript apps on IOS is easy as breakpoints can be set and variables examined in the remote debugger . I am hoping the same capabilities are in IE10 and would appreciate any information on where to enable these very much needed capabilities.

Answer (score 22):

The bad news, that there is no new debug capabilities in comparison to WP7/IE9. Please take a look on [How do I debug Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198808/how-do-i-debug-internet-explorer-on-windows-phone-7) since we are in exactly the same situation on WP8.

What I personally use on daily basis

1. Debug your app in IE10 Desktop as much as possible
2. [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) remote debugger. [Demo video.](https://vimeo.com/47159911) You can use the following app based on Weinre to simplify its usage (no local setup needed) - [IeMobileDebugger src](https://github.com/sgrebnov/IeMobileDebugger) or [link to Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=dd032799-1fd9-4ba5-9135-4589908063e7)

   Supports

   Html traversing
   Html node styles, properties, metrics
   Reading console output
   Executing js on device side from console (including intellisense)
   Dynamic script injection - ability to debug live sites

   Not supported

   js breakpoints
3. For javascript line by line debugging use [aardwolf](http://lexandera.com/aardwolf/). [Demo with VS integration](https://vimeo.com/58078616).
4. To redirect console trace to Visual Studio output and be able to use console.log("some message") for tracing

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.console = {
        log: function (str) { window.external.Notify(str); }
    };

    // output errors to console log
    window.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log("window.onerror ::" + JSON.stringify(e));
    };

    console.log("Installed console !");
</script>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Browser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
    // Add your URL here
    Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative));

    Browser.ScriptNotify += (s, arg) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(arg.Value);
    };           
}
```

Comment: thanks this is extremely helpful but I was curious about the tracing. Are u saying that if I am in phone simulator running my Phonegap app I will see the console output in Visual Studio? That is good news in itself , just too bad the IE team does not look at how Webkit debugging works on the phones as it is wonderful!

Comment: Yes, under Cordova/PhoneGap console.log() calls are redirected to Visual Studio Output window.

Comment: Great answer! With Cordova/PhoneGap I just had to add "WebBrowser Browser = new WebBrowser();" to the MainPage class

Comment: I believe 'WebBrowser Browser = new WebBrowser();' line is not required since Browser control instance must be already on the MainPage and the Browser_Loaded method is called than that control is being loaded.

Comment: Except that winre is only available for webkit browsers, hence no chance for `Windows Phone` / `IE`

Comment: Actually it is not longer true. Weinre supports IE10+ and FF.

Answer (score 17):

FWIW: Windows Phone 8.1 finally supports remote debugging. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/04/04/diagnosing-mobile-website-issues-on-windows-phone-8-1-with-visual-studio.aspx

Comment: Note you need VS 2013/VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

While not a full solution, Lauri Piispanen's [consolelog.js](https://github.com/lauripiispanen/consolelog.js), a nodejs-based remote JS console logger could help you.