# Connect Windows Phone 8 to Weinre

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, weinre

I am trying to connect a Windows Phone 8 device to a local Weinre server. I think the requirements for the client are a WebKit based internet browser which I don't think Internet Explorer is(?) Can somebody confirm whether it's possible to connect a Windows Phone 8 device to Weinre? If so, then how? It doesn't seem to work via the usual reference scripts.

I've seen a post on here which shows a Windows Phone 8 device is temporarily connecting but drops. I can't even get that!

Many thanks if you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Weinre now works on Windows Phone 8 exactly the same way as on other platforms like Android or iPhone. To run Weinre client use Chrome or any other webkit browsers. I would recommend the following to identify the problem.

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of Weinre
2. Check Firewall settings (you can temporary disable it). Use ip address when linking weinre target.js to your html page.
3. Add console.log as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14567491/windows-8-phone-ie10-javascript-debugging/14569780#14569780) to see if there is any error while running Weinre target script on WP8 device
4. Try adding the following script instead of full Weinre local set up. For more details see [Debugging Cordova Apps on Wp8](http://sgrebnov.blogspot.ru/2012/12/debugging-cordova-apps-on-wp8.html)

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> window.WeinreServerId = "wp_test"; // <-- your unique identifier on the server below
> window.WeinreServerURL = "http://debug.phonegap.com"; // <-- weinre server to use
>
> // To open debugger use the following uri format - WeinreServerURL/client/#WeinreServerId
> // for example http://debug.phonegap.com/client/#wp_test
>
> </script>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23085338/weinre-target-script-min.js"></script>
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much! This has helped a huge amount.