# localStorage not working with IE 10 throwing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-phone-8, local-storage, internet-explorer-10

I am making a Windows 8 Phone app using HTML 5 project template.

I have download **jquery-1.9.1.js** using nuget and also have downloaded **jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js** from [here](http://jquerymobile.com/download/) and have added them to my project.

Now I am using the following code, I am trying to use `localStorage`, my below code works with Chrome and Firefox, but not with IE 10.

**Common.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jquery started");
    localStorage.selectedCategory = "cc";
    alert("After assignment");
    alert(localStorage.selectedCategory);
})
```

When i run this in IE 10 I get the following error messages in console, and only my first alert "jquery started" is shown, the rest of the alerts are not shown.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference 
>       jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js, line 2536 character 5
>
> SCRIPT5007: Unable to set property 'selectedCategory' of undefined or null reference 
>       common.js, line 3 character 2

[image]

The moment I comment out the localStorage code, all alerts are shown, but still one of the error remains in the console.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'msie' of undefined or null reference 
>   jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js, line 2536 character 5

[image]

I just dont seem to understand the problem, please help me out on this.

**EDIT :**
My html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/html/css/phone.css" />
        <title>Interview QA</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Custom/common.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
      <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795286/localstorage-not-working-with-windows-8-phone-html-5-project-template

Answer (score 2):

You probably need the correct doctype:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Comment: yes I am using that. I have updated my question with the html that I am using; please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Look at hexacyanide's answer - it might be the correct one for you.

Comment: yes, that did solved my 2nd problem. But still getting the same errors when using localStorage. How do resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

I too got the same error. But when I replaced "localStorage" with the keyword "Storage", it worked in ie10. Modify your your code like this and try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("jquery started");
    Storage.selectedCategory = "cc";
    alert("After assignment");
    alert(Storage.selectedCategory); })
```

**Update:** But this is not equivalent to local storage, because this get cleared when the page is refreshed. When further explored found that localStorage is not working with file:// protocol in ie10. However if you host your page under a web server(IIS/Tomcat etc.,) and access it through http:// protocol, localStorage works just fine in ie10.

Answer (score 0):

jquery have removed $.browser and browser checking code so please use jquery migrate.js which will avoid this issue.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/15/jquery-1-9-final-jquery-2-0-beta-migrate-final-released/