# How to monitor cordova application log in WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I created cordova application using cordova cli. Is there any way to monitor logs for my application ?

Answer (score 1):

For C# part there is possibility (Visual Studio allows you to completely debug it), but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

I assume you are looking for JavaScript logs for your Cordova application. There is no possibility to debug the JavaScript code according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757061.aspx) nor is it possible to collect the console output directly.

However remote debugging should be possible as described by [Sergei Grebnov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569780/1744702). As he also tells there, it is quite working solution to debug as much as possible on desktop browser. It has worked quite well for me until adding much plugins..